# How many users can i add in a folder in Power BI report Server

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to add 8000 users with role "Content Manager" in a folder in Power BI Report Server throw Web Service. But it is only able to add 1820 users. If I am trying to add more than 1820 user it is throwing below error.

> "Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details."

I am getting the same error while trying to add through Report Server Web Portal.

Does anyone have any idea about this?